# R ggplot highlight table of quarterly figures has displaced figures

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am using geom_tile to create a table of quarterly figures, which is contained in a data frame. This seems to work without problems except when the data series begins in the middle of the year, typically in the April to June quarter. If I plot the data frame at the beginning of the calendar year, there is no problem: I get a well-formed highlight table.

[image: from start of CY]

However, to achieve that I have also excluded some of my data. If I specify a start date part way through the year, the data gets dispaced/jumbled up, like so:

[image]

Q. How can I plot the table such that even when the series begins in mid-year it somehow pads any missing data for the year in which it starts? That is, if my data begins in the July to September quarter, how can I force ggplot to put that first data point in the third column, leaving two blank tiles to the left?

Q. As a follow-up or perhaps the same question asked in a different way, how can I specify which quarter should be in the first column? Ideally I would like to be able to specify that the Jul-Sep quarter of each year is in the first column of the table and that the January to March quarter is in the fourth column.

Example follows:

```
require(lubridate)
require(ggplot2)

set.seed(12345)
df <- data.frame(date=seq(as.Date("2003/06/01"), by="month", length.out=103),myval=runif(103, min=-1, max=1))
df$date <- (df$date + months(1)) - days(1) # get last day of month
df$year <- as.numeric(format(as.Date(df$date), format="%Y"))
df$month <- as.numeric(format(as.Date(df$date), format="%m"))
# create quarterly label
df$qtr <- ifelse(df$month==3,"Jan-Mar",ifelse(df$month==6,"Apr-Jun",ifelse(df$month==9,"Jul-Sep",ifelse(df$month==12,"Oct-Dec",""))))
qtr <- df[ df$month %in% c(3,6,9,12), ] # extract quarter-end figures

p <- ggplot(qtr[qtr$date>='2004-01-01',], aes(x=qtr,y=year(date), fill = myval, label = sprintf("%1.1f%%", 100*myval))) + 
  scale_y_date(major="years", format="%Y") +
  scale_y_reverse(breaks=2003:2012, labels=2003:2012, expand=c(0,0)) + 
  geom_tile() + geom_text(size=geomtextsize,colour = "black") +
  scale_fill_gradient2(low = "blue", high = "red",,midpoint=0) +
  scale_x_discrete(expand=c(0,0))

print(p)
```

**EDIT:**
An image showing the final improved version incorporating Vincent's suggestions and the code used to generate it follow below.

[image: final version of highlight table]

```
set.seed(12345)
df <- data.frame(date=seq(as.Date("2003/06/01"), by="month", length.out=103),myval=runif(103, min=-1, max=1))
df$date <- (df$date + months(1)) - days(1) # get last day of month
df$year <- as.numeric(format(as.Date(df$date), format="%Y"))
df$month <- as.numeric(format(as.Date(df$date), format="%m"))
# create quarterly label
df$qtr <- ifelse(df$month==3,"Jan-Mar",ifelse(df$month==6,"Apr-Jun",ifelse(df$month==9,"Jul-Sep",ifelse(df$month==12,"Oct-Dec",""))))
df$qtr[ df$qtr=="" ] <- NA
df$display_year <- ifelse( df$month < 4, df$year - 1, df$year )
df$display_year <- paste( df$display_year, df$display_year + 1, sep="-" )
df$qtr <- ordered(df$qtr, levels=c("Apr-Jun", "Jul-Sep", "Oct-Dec", "Jan-Mar"))
qtr <- df[ df$month %in% c(3,6,9,12), ]
qtr$display_year <- factor( qtr$display_year, levels = sort( unique(qtr$display_year), decreasing=TRUE ) )

p <- ggplot(qtr, aes(x=qtr,y=display_year, fill = myval, label = sprintf("%1.1f%%", 100*myval))) + 
scale_y_discrete(expand=c(0,0)) +
geom_tile() + geom_text(size=geomtextsize,colour = "black") +
scale_fill_gradient2(low = "blue", high = "red",,midpoint=0) +
scale_x_discrete(expand=c(0,0))
p
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can enforce the order of the quarters by ensuring they are of type `ordered`.

```
df$qtr[ df$qtr=="" ] <- NA
df$qtr <- ordered(df$qtr, 
  levels=c("Jan-Mar", "Apr-Jun", "Jul-Sep", "Oct-Dec"))
```

For the second question, 
you also need to change the year column to be the April-to-March year.

```
df$display_year <- ifelse( df$month < 4, df$year - 1, df$year )
df$display_year <- paste( df$display_year, df$display_year + 1, sep="-" )
# Check the data
df[,c("year", "month", "qtr", "display_year")]
# Small change in the plot: the y axis is no longer a date
df$qtr <- ordered(df$qtr, levels=c("Apr-Jun", "Jul-Sep", "Oct-Dec", "Jan-Mar"))
qtr <- df[ df$month %in% c(3,6,9,12), ]
p <- ggplot(qtr[qtr$date>='2004-01-01',], aes(x=qtr,y=display_year, fill = myval, label = sprintf("%1.1f%%", 100*myval))) + 
  scale_y_discrete(expand=c(0,0)) +
  geom_tile() + geom_text(size=geomtextsize,colour = "black") +
  scale_fill_gradient2(low = "blue", high = "red",,midpoint=0) +
  scale_x_discrete(expand=c(0,0))
p
```

Comment: Vincent, thanks, this works just as requested and neatly resolves the main problem. I had blindly assumed that there was some 'natural' ordering at work, but when I looked at the output of `levels(df$qtr)` it was `NULL`. After applying your proposed solution it becomes `[1] "Jan-Mar" "Apr-Jun" "Jul-Sep" "Oct-Dec"`. Would you have any ideas on the second question? I immediately tried reordering so that Apr-Jun come first in the levels but could not get that to work.

Comment: When a character vector is transformed into a factor, the order in which the various strings appears is used. I have updated my answer for your second question.

Comment: Aha, that worked. It also had the unwanted side-effect of inverting the Y axis, so that 2011 is at the top and 2003 at the bottom. I tried to re-order this using `levels(qtr$display_year) <- as.character(unique(qtr[order(qtr$display_year),]$year))` but it didn't have any effect. I tried various variations on scale_y_reverse but with no luck. Clearly I still have some way to go before I understand factors...

Comment: You just need to sort the levels: `qtr$display_year <- factor( qtr$display_year, levels = sort( unique(qtr$display_year), decreasing=TRUE ) )`. You could also specify the desired order in `scale_y_discrete`.